# gcc 5.4.1 can not compile a file

Tags: 16.04, gcc

> gcc   -c  hello.c

doesn't work, there is no .o file generated. And nothing warnings.
My system is ubuntu 16.04, this happened after system upgrade.
and gcc -v show forllow messeage:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.1 20160904 (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04)
```

hello.c is forllowing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is caused by another problem, And @ducvd provide a good method of debugging.

Comment: Your question didn't mention anything about how to debug your code, however I tested your code by compiling it with the accepted answer of the linked question before posting the link so I know that it works. That's why I flagged it as a duplicate question, not because of the debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use verbose mode for output generation, and you could looks what error is.

```
gcc -v -c hello.c
```

Comment: No prob, it's fine when you found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Thank @ducvd again.
when i run this command:
gcc -v -c hello.c
the output is:

```
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu hello.c -quiet -dumpbase hello.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase hello -version -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccgCfljP.s
GNU C11 (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04) version 5.4.1 20160904 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.4.1 20160904, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C11 (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04) version 5.4.1 20160904 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.4.1 20160904, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 0d1f484395ede84b192d061a0b021ec8
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o hello.o /tmp/ccgCfljP.s
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

Preprocess is good, but things goes to wrong when executing command **as**, to compile .c to .o file.
So I check whether **as** is normal，found **as** in the path:

> /usr/local/bin/as

this is a useless symbol link. The **as** used for compilation should be located：

> /usr/bin/as

when I delete /usr/local/bin/as，anything works well for me!

Tanks @ducvd again!